# mismatch not picked up when one value is null

Tags: sql, null

I have a simple SQL query where a comparison is done between two tables for mismatching value.
Yesterday, we picked up an issue where one field was null and the other wasn't, but a mismatch was not detected.
As far as I can determine,the logic has been working all along until yesterday.
Here is the logic of the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(UserID INT,PlayDate DATETIME)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(UserID INT,PlayDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO Table1 (UserID)
SELECT 5346

INSERT INTO Table2 (UserID,PlayDate)
SELECT 5346,'2012-11-01'

SELECT a.UserID
FROM   Table1 a
INNER JOIN
       Table2 b
ON     a.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE  a.PlayDate <> b.PlayDate
```

No values are returned even though the PlayDate values are different.

I have now updated the WHERE to read:

```
WHERE  ISNULL(a.PlayDate,'') <> ISNULL(b.PlayDate,'')
```

Is there a setting in SQL which someone could have changed to cause the original code to no longer pick up the difference in fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
NULL <> anything
```

is `unknown` not `true`. SQL uses three valued logic (false/true/unknown) and the predicate needs to evaluate to `true` in a `where` clause for the row to be returned.

In fact in standard SQL any comparison with `NULL` except for `IS [NOT] NULL` yields `unknown`. Including `WHERE NULL = NULL`

You don't state RDBMS but if it supports `IS DISTINCT FROM` you could use that or if you are using MySQL it has a null safe equality operator [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) you could negate.

You say you think it previously behaved differently. If you are on SQL Server you might be using a different setting for [`ANSI_NULLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) somehow but this setting is deprecated and you should rewrite any code that depends on it anyway.

You can simulate `IS DISTINCT FROM` in SQL Server with `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.PlayDate EXCEPT SELECT b.PlayDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Not even a NULL can be equal to NULL.

- Here are two common queries that just don’t work:

> `select * from table where column = null;`
>
> `select * from table where column <> null;`

- there is no concept of equality or inequality, greater than or less
  than with `NULL`s. Instead, one can only say “is” or “is not”
  (without the word “equal”) when discussing `NULL`s.

### - The correct way to write the queries

> select * from table where column IS NULL;
>
> select * from table where column IS NOT NULL;